# Facebook API post to page with page credentials

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was using a call to the facebook API to post news published in my website to our facebook page with a CURL call

```
$message= $facebook . " http://www.k-pop.com.mx/nota/".$date."/".$latestnews;
            //Post to facebook
            $data['picture'] = "http://www.k-pop.com.mx/images/news/".$ultima_noticia . "-" . $imageslug . ".jpg";
            $data['link'] = "http://www.k-pop.com.mx/nota/".$date."/".$imageslug;
            $data['message'] = $facebook;
            $data['caption'] = "K-Pop Mexico";
            $data['description'] = $descripcion;

            $data['access_token'] = "MY_LONG_ACCESS_TOKEN";
            $post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID/feed';

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $return = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
```

but since a couple of days the posts have been publishing with my facebook personal user, instead of the page name.

I debugged my tokens to check if something was missing, but the token is there, I even created a new extended token with the next scopes:

```
user_birthday, user_photos, user_videos, user_friends, email, publish_actions, manage_pages, publish_pages, business_management, pages_messaging, pages_messaging_phone_number, public_profile
```

Did facebook change something or is there an extra step I'm missing?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I needed to create a page access token, by calling the url

https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN

This returned a page access token and by using that token on the call the problem was fixed.